# Sonicwall DHCP client option code

Tags: dhcp, sonicwall

Is it possible to set DHCP option codes for the DHCP **client** (the WAN interface)?

I am quite sure that you can send options in a DHCP request, I quote: "This option is used by DHCP clients to specify their unique identifier..." (RFC 2132, 9.14). My ISP requires me to send option code 60 with value "IPTV_RG".

I really hope sonicwall can do this.

Comment: Even if you could send something like that to your ISP's server, it is unlikely that your ISP will honor the option, unless your business has a contract with the ISP to honor such things. You can check your contract and/or contact the ISP. What an ISP will or will not do for your business is contained in the business contract with the ISP.

Comment: As explained in comments below, what he wants to do is send Option 60 Vendor Class Identifier = "IPTV_RG", which is absolutely reasonable.  I edited the question to include the comment.

Comment: @jonathanjo, I understand it is reasonable. My comment is that even if he manages to send it, he should not expect the ISP to honor it unless it is part of the contract his business has with the ISP. I'm just making sure that he is not completely disappointed with the results.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

DHCP servers accept very few options from clients; though as you point out in comments a few options are sent by the client in the DHCP REQUEST, such as `Vendor class identifier` (option 60) and the more-common `Client Identifier` (option 61) and `Parameter Request List` (option 55).

I've found no way to send this option from a Sonicwall.

It's no help to you, but in Cisco it's `ip dhcp client class-id WORD` inside the the interface configuration.

Comment: I know you can set option codes for the DHCP server, but I want to send an option code to my ISP's DHCP server, so my DHCP client (running on the WAN interface) needs to be able to send an option code along.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were after, answer edited.  What option are you wanting to set?  What model and software do you have?

Comment: I am quite sure that you can send options in a DHCP request, I quote: "This option is used by DHCP clients to specify their unique identifier..." (RFC 2132, 9.14).

My ISP requires me to send option code 60 with value "IPTV_RG". I really hope sonicwall can do this. (same message as I replied to Zac67)

Comment: Edited answer again now that I understand what you're after: I know it's not helpful for you, but I added Cisco solution to help clarify the question.  Sorry couldn't help you better.  I edited your question to include you comment to prevent more of us misunderstanding what you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Check [RFC 2132](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132): DHCP options are passed from the server to the client, not the other way around.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could just set the desired option parameter manually on the Sonicwall (e.g. DNS server).

Comment: I am quite sure that you can send options in a DHCP request, I quote: "This option is used by DHCP clients to specify their unique identifier..." (RFC 2132, 9.14).

My ISP requires me to send option code 60 with value "IPTV_RG". I really hope sonicwall can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the sonic wall will let you set options when you set your WAN interface as dhcp client but you could test before buying it in case you haven't yet at the following website: https://livedemo.sonicwall.com/MOBILE/#NGFW you choose your product and it will take you to the a web gui of the product.